# Toggle between two different tag contents using checkbox

Tags: html, jquery, checkbox, togglebutton

HTML

```
<body class="music">
  <pre class="chord">Chords</pre>
  <div class="lyric" style="display: none">Lyrics</div>
  <input class="c" id="event" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" width="5px" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="info" data-on="Chords" data-off="Lyrics">
</body>
```

Please help me with jquery code. By default only pre tag contents are displayed. When checkbox is checked I need to display only the contents of div tag. When box is unchecked, I want the reverse to be happened i.e. only show contents of pre tag.

Comment: The simplest way to do this is to use jQuery toggle, which would change the css `display` value of the element to `hide`/`show` based on current value.
Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63091686/1401808 Can I ask why do you have `data-on` and `data-off` attributes?

Comment: The reason for using `data-on` and `data-off` are shown here: https://jsfiddle.net/5ox6ynm7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,continuing the comment earlier, here's the code that you may want to use.

```
$(function(){
  var chord = $(".chord");
  var lyric = $(".lyric");
  var event = $("#event");
  event.on("change", function(){
    chord.toggle();
    lyric.toggle();
  });
})
```

by leveraging the data attributes in your HTML, a better way to do it is to update `pre` content based on checkbox selection

```js
$(function(){
    var selection = $(".selection");
    var event = $("#event");
    event.on("change", function(){
        var content = $(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).data("on") : $(this).data("off");
        selection.text(content);
    });
})
```

```html
<script 
    src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js">
</script>
<body class="music">
  <pre class="selection">Chords</pre>
  <input
    class="c"
    id="event"
    type="checkbox"
    checked data-toggle="toggle"
    data-size="small"
    width="5px"
    data-onstyle="info"
    data-offstyle="info"
    data-on="Chords"
    data-off="Lyrics" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="content1">Content 1</div>
<div id="content2">Content 2</div>
<input type="checkbox" checked id="checkbox">
```

CSS:

```
#content2 {
    display: none;
}
```

JS (using JQuery):

```
$(function() {
    $('#checkbox').on('click', function() {
        if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#content1').hide();
            $('#content2').show();
        } else {
            $('#content1').show();
            $('#content2').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

If you have any questions, ask.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to toggle the displays.  I replaced the pre tag with a div for spacing

```js
function jsdisplay(){
$(".chord").eq(0).toggle();
$(".lyric").eq(0).toggle();
}
```

```css
pre{
margin:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="music">
  <pre class="chord">Chords</pre>
  <div class="lyric" style="display: none">Lyrics</div>
  <input class="c" id="event" type="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-size="small" width="5px" data-onstyle="info" data-offstyle="info" data-on="Chords" data-off="Lyrics" onchange="jsdisplay()">
</body>
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't change pre tag.

Comment: then don't. it will work either way. just add margin:0 if you want the same placement

Comment: Actually this is a demo example. I need to write long texts inside tag and  preserve white spaces.